# Find z-transform and plot it's pole-zero map with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this function:

x[n] = (1/2) ^ n * u[n] + (-1/3) ^ n * u[n]

I need to do two things with this using MATLAB:

1. Find it's *z*-transform.
2. Plot it's poles and zeros.

I am using the following code:

```
syms n;
f = (1/2)^n + (-1/3)^n;
F = ztrans(f);
```

I get the *z*-transform in the `F` variable, but I can't see how to create it's pole-zero plot. I am using the built-in function `pzmap` (`pzmap(F);`), but it doesn't seem to work with the output of `ztrans(f)`.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change the *z*-transform into some other form like like a transfer function model or a zero-pole gain model? If so, can someone explain how that can be done using the output of `ztrans(f)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first bit of code you gave uses symbolic math to solve for the *z*-transform. You'll need to convert the output to a [discrete-time model](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/creating-discrete-time-models.html) supported by the Control System toolbox.

```
syms n;
f = (1/2)^n + (-1/3)^n;
F = ztrans(f)
```

returns `z/(z - 1/2) + z/(z + 1/3)`. You can optionally use [`collect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/collect.html) to convert this

```
F2 = collect(F)
```

to `(12*z^2 - z)/(6*z^2 - z - 1)`. Then you'll want to find the coefficients of the polynomials in the numerator and denominator and create a discrete-time transfer function object with [`tf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) for a particular sampling period:

```
[num,den] = numden(F2);
Ts = 0.1; % Sampling period
H = tf(sym2poly(num),sym2poly(den),Ts)
```

Then `pzmap(H)` will produce a plot like this:

[image: Pole-Zero Map plot]